Non-iterative algorithm of obtaining the eigenvalues of a symmetrical matrix of any size
My task is to solve the nuclear Schrodinger equation of a multi-atomic molecule in the "Rigid Rotor - Harmonic Oscillator" approximation. I have a matrix U (size N*N) of the force constants - second derivatives of the energy by Cartesian atomic coordinates (the first derivatives must be close to zero). This matrix is symmetrical: Uij=Uji. Some people have told me that this matrix (in mass-weighted coordinates) must be diagonalized, and the values on the diagonal will represent the harmonic frequencies which are needed. However I don’t fully understand what is the “diagonalization”, and I’ve heard that there are different types of diagonalization. Probably what I need is finding the eigenvalues of the U matrix.
I know the Jacobi diagonalization algorithm, it is very possible that it will solve my task. However I feel slightly uncertain with this algorithm, because it is iterative; I thought I should better find a non-iterative algorithm, because the non-iterative ones are more fast and accurate. Can you suggest such an algorithm?
A colleague has said that my task (computing the eigenvalues) can be solved using the NumPy library; I don't know whether this library uses the Jacobi diagonalization routine or something faster (what I want).

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Finding the eigenvalues requires solving an $N$-th degree polynomial so iterative methods will likely be the fastest. I'd also recommend the NumPy library for such calculations since they're optimized for exactly this purpose. Note that they have specific algorithms for symmetric matrices to speed them up.
